# pytest how to select or skip a test method with parameters combined like this?

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I know how to use `-k` to select or skip the test items in pytest. But as in my case, the source code used some decorators to generate a combination of parameters sets for some test classes like this (from [github cupy tests folder][1]):

```
# This class compares CUB results against NumPy's
@testing.parameterize(*testing.product({
    'shape': [(10,), (10, 20), (10, 20, 30), (10, 20, 30, 40)],
    'order': ('C', 'F'),
    'backend': ('device', 'block'),
}))
@testing.gpu
@unittest.skipUnless(cupy.cuda.cub.available, 'The CUB routine is not enabled')
class TestCubReduction(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.old_routine_accelerators = _acc.get_routine_accelerators()
        self.old_reduction_accelerators = _acc.get_reduction_accelerators()
        if self.backend == 'device':
            _acc.set_routine_accelerators(['cub'])
            _acc.set_reduction_accelerators([])
        elif self.backend == 'block':
            _acc.set_routine_accelerators([])
            _acc.set_reduction_accelerators(['cub'])

    def tearDown(self):
        _acc.set_routine_accelerators(self.old_routine_accelerators)
        _acc.set_reduction_accelerators(self.old_reduction_accelerators)

    @testing.for_contiguous_axes()
    @testing.for_all_dtypes(no_bool=True)
    @testing.numpy_cupy_allclose(rtol=1E-5)
    def test_cub_min(self, xp, dtype, axis):
```

I used pytest with `--collect-only -qq` to collect out the test items. And for the case I want to select is:

```
core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py::TestCubReduction_param_7_{backend='device', order='F', shape=(10, 20, 30, 40)}::test_cub_max
```

But if I directly use pytest to do this test, it will raise error:

```
$ pytest -v core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py::TestCubReduction_param_7_{backend='device', order='F', shape=(10, 20, 30, 40)}::test_cub_max
```

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
I tried to escape the '(' in bash command, but still get an error:

```
$ pytest -v core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py::TestCubReduction_param_7_{backend='device', order='F', shape=\(10, 20, 30, 40\)}::test_cub_max
================================================================================================================ test session starts ================================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.6.8', 'Platform': 'Linux-5.4.0-65-generic-x86_64-with-centos-7.9.2009-Core', 'Packages': {'pytest': '6.2.5', 'py': '1.11.0', 'pluggy': '1.0.0'}, 'Plugins': {'metadata': '1.11.0', 'html': '3.1.1', 'excel': '1.4.2'}}
rootdir: /home/liwei.dai/tests/swfw/experiment/cupy, configfile: setup.cfg
plugins: metadata-1.11.0, html-3.1.1, excel-1.4.2
collected 0 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

=============================================================================================================== no tests ran in 0.01s ===============================================================================================================
ERROR: file or directory not found: order=F,
```

Furthermore, If I want to test all items on this file but skipping those with backend='device' or items containing jittify='True', how could that be done?
I tried with `-k`, but `=` symbol is not allowed in `-k` values. Please help me out.

Edit:
You can provide solutions by using either pytest or unittest, both are welcomed, thanks in advance.
[1]: https://github.com/cupy/cupy/blob/master/tests/cupy_tests/core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py#L328

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this locally, but it absolutely looks like a `shell` issue rather than a `python` one per se.

When you call `pytest`, you are passing a list of parameters to that program.  In this case you do it this way:

```sh
$ pytest -v core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py::TestCubReduction_param_7_{backend='device', order='F', shape=\(10, 20, 30, 40\)}::test_cub_max
```

Which means you are passing `-v`, `core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py::TestCubReduction_param_7_{backend='device',`, `order='F',` and `shape=\(10, 20, 30, 40\)}::test_cub_max`.

We can read from `pytest --help` that the parameters it expects are:

```sh
jose@almanzora ~ % pytest --help
usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
```

Thus said, it will consider that after the options (In your case `-v`) there are a **space separated** list of filenames.  Therefore, you should scape the spaces in your argument if you want `pytest` to treat them as a single one.

Comment: Thanks. But I tried your suggestion to remove the spaces:`pytest -v core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py::TestCubReduction_param_7_{backend='device',order='F',shape=\(10,20,30,40\)}::test_cub_max`, I can see another error:`ERROR: file or directory not found: core_tests/test_ndarray_reduction.py::TestCubReduction_param_7_backend=device::test_cub_max`. It seems that a lot of things get truncated here.

Comment: Well, this is a similar error, related to the shell and not Python.  You are telling Python to open a file that does not exist.  Be sure the syntax you are using (Colons `:` and equals `=`) is correct.